# Which one drain battery slower, airplay or hdmi?

Tags: airplay

Two ways of showing video on TV are airplay through Apple TV and hdmi cable.
Which one drain the battery of ipad/ iPhone / ... Slower?

Comment: I would assume that HDMI uses less power than Airplay (especially if you also turn off the Wi-Fi) but I don't have data to back that up so I won't give you a definite answer.

Comment: hdmi over an adapter-cable? i think the great plus from using air play is that you can put your iPhone/iPad onto a table next to your tv chair an let it connected to the Power - thats what i do no need to buy an extra hdmi connection kit so 2 more beers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending how scientific you want to go, the direct cable would normaly consume less power then wireless transfer.

That is true when using the correct cable (high quality) since the cables also have some resistance (power consumption) specially if they are very long.

To find actual power consumption differences you need one of those power monitoring apps. (many options on the web).

Is it worth knowing? probably not, since you have to monitor it for like 2 hours, without other applications running to get meaningful numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The HDMi adapter uses a lot of power as it is also doing video conversion. It even drains your bettery while NOT showing video, just by being plugged in.